# Where should I ask a design question for a .NET Windows application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a design question involving the arrangement of menus. It is not a specific programming question, although I am using C# in Visual Studio.

What is the best Stack Exchange site to ask that question on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a design question involving the arrangement of menus

If your question is about the usability, then [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) is your best bet. There are a lot of questions how to design the UI so it is best from UX point of view.

Make sure to read their [help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make sure your question is on-topic there.

Comment: @CigarDoug: did you post your question already? Did UX work out for you?